# LiClipse and execute codes in console shortcuts?

Tags: eclipse, console, pydev, interactive

For Eclipse PyDev, you can select a few lines of codes, then hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter to execute the codes in interactive console, but with LiClipse, that simply removes the selected codes, I can't find anywhere mentioning this, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is a feature of PyDev, so, it'll only work if you open the .py files with the PyDev editor (i.e.: in preferences > general > editors > file associations check that '*.py' is marked to be opened with the 'Python Editor' -- for PyDev -- and not the 'LiClipse Python Editor').

Alternatively you can right click a file and choose 'open with > Python Editor'.

After that, Ctrl+Alt+Enter should work for you (note that in the latest version, Ctrl+Alt+Enter is really for opening the editor, but F2 is the recommended way of sending things line-by-line to the console... See: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html for details).

Comment: Changed to Python Editor, Ctrl Shift Enter still don't work, but F2 is better, one finger rules.

Comment: Sorry about that. It should've been Ctrl+Alt+Enter -- fixed the answer... and yes, F2 is much better :)