# PyDev doesn't execute shortcut to send current line to console

Tags: python, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, pydev

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380281/liclipse-and-execute-codes-in-console-shortcuts) and the [PyDev documentation on the interactive console](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html), pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> should send the current line from the PyDev editor to the Python console.

I have a Python file open in the Python editor (I made sure of this by opening it "Open With" --> "Python Editor") and have started a console session by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Nonetheless, when I press <kbd>F2</kbd>, nothing happens. I have to select the line I'm interested in and send it to the console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I've checked my keybinding options under "Window" --> "Preferences" --> "General" --> "Keys" and am unable to see any differences between the settings for the commands "Execute line in console", which is mapped to <kbd>F2</kbd>, and "Interactive Console", which is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. However, the second command works whereas the first does not. I've also tried mapping the command to other keys, but that hasn't changed the results at all. Any tips on how I can use this command?

Comment: I have the same problem. It worked a few days ago. Now it doesn't work anymore. It might be that upgrading to Debian Jessie broke it for me.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem with F2 specifically, because other F-key shortcuts work and if I change shortcut for "send line to console" to some non F-keys it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have any solution since the time you posted your question?

Answer (score 2):

I had that problem. All shortcuts worked except F2. 
I tried many things without success.
But in the end. Simply restarting Eclipse solved the problem.

Comment: i think it might have something to do with emacs keybindings?  I'm having a similar issue...

Comment: @joefromct : So in my case it was working before, then it suddenly stopped working. I checked key-bindings and everything but none of that fixed the problem. However after restarting eclipse everything was working again.

Comment: I've found that closing the file and re-opening fixes the issue.