# PyDev: execute line in interactive console (f2) does not work

Tags: pydev

After updating to pydev version 6.3.3 (by reinstalling LiClipse) the 
F2 shortcut does not work properly. Althought I can start the interactive console with the shortcut, it is not possible to send the lines to the console by F2. Ctrl+Alt+Enter works, but F2 does not.

Restarting Liclipse like proposed here does not work...[PyDev doesn't execute shortcut to send current line to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646974/pydev-doesnt-execute-shortcut-to-send-current-line-to-console)

Comment: Also when making a figure with matplotlib 2.2.2 in the interactive mode, there is no window opening like before with matplotlib 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

At the end the only way to fix the problem was downgrading to PyDev 6.2 (by copying manually to the eclipse/dropins folder). This made it necessary to downgrade matplotlib to 2.1.2 and ipython to 5.4.1 (python 2.7)....